# TypeScript Integration with existing Node js express project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I Want to develop node js express application with typescript. To integrate typescript in node js I followed a few tutorials from online and it is working as expected. but .ts files converted .js and it is stored in dist folder but I don't want like that. can I run my project with only with .ts files instead of converting to .js files in dist folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

Install it globally:

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

Run app.ts:

```
ts-node app.ts
```

Answering your question in comments:

First run `tsc --init` to create `tsconfig.json` automatically.
Then install `npm i @types/node` and `npm i @types/express`

In ./routes/index.ts:

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express'
export function Hello(req: Request ,res: Response) {
    res.send('Hello World')
}
```

In app.ts

```
import express from 'express'; 
const app = express(); 
import {Hello} from './routes/index' 
app.get('/', Hello); 
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Comment: TypeError: routes\index.js: Emit skipped  getting this error

Comment: import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import indexRouter from './routes/index'

app.get('/', indexRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));

Comment: @RajeshYadav kindly accept it by clicking the check icon beside the answer

Comment: @RajeshYadav see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work